# NSTableView not displaying in NSView

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

New to Swift, I am trying to implement an NSTableView in my SwiftUI macOS (>= 12.2) app. The table view is being added as a subview of an NSView, but the table view is not displaying on the screen.

**Update 1**:

- A minimal reproducible example was added at the end of the post
- The code was updated to conform to advice from @jnpdx

**Note:** If uncommenting the line `//addSubview(tableView)` in `configureTableView()`, (so that there is a duplicate `addSubview(tableView)` call) you can see a slim table at the very bottom

**Update 2:** It appears that both `addSubview(tableView)` lines may be needed for the tableView to be a descendant view of CustomView in the view hierarchy, and displayed within the bounds of the CustomView instance. It apparently would not create a separate instance. *If that's the case, then the current issue is just the table's positioning at the bottom of the app view (which should be at the top) and ensuring the text box's visibility*

Here is the implementation for my FilesView class, which is a subview of the CustomView class:

```
class FilesView: NSView {
    let files: Files
    @Published var selectedFile: AudioFile? = nil
    @Published var sortDescending = false
    var tableView = NSTableView()
    var nameColumn = NSTableColumn(identifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "name"))
    var statusColumn = NSTableColumn(identifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "status"))
    var dateColumn = NSTableColumn(identifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "date"))
    var groupingColumn = NSTableColumn(identifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "grouping"))
    var durationColumn = NSTableColumn(identifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "duration"))
    init(files:Files){
        self.files = files
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        configureTableView()
    }
    func addFile(file: AudioFile) {
        self.files.files.append(file)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }   
    func configureTableView() {
        print("in configureTableView()")
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.identifier = NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "cell")
        tableView.addTableColumn(nameColumn)
        tableView.addTableColumn(statusColumn)
        tableView.addTableColumn(dateColumn)
        tableView.addTableColumn(groupingColumn)
        tableView.addTableColumn(durationColumn)
        tableView.headerView = nil
        tableView.backgroundColor = .black
        tableView.usesAlternatingRowBackgroundColors = true
        tableView.gridStyleMask = .solidVerticalGridLineMask
        tableView.focusRingType = .none
        tableView.selectionHighlightStyle = .none
        tableView.rowSizeStyle = .default
        tableView.reloadData()
        //addSubview(tableView) // tableView is a subview of FilesView and FilesView is a subview of CustomView, tableView will be added as a subview of CustomView when CustomView is created and tableView is passed as a parameter.
    }
}
```

And here is the implementation for the CustomView class:

```
class CustomView: NSView {
    private let tableView: FilesView
    private let textView: TextBox

    init(tableView: FilesView, textView: TextBox) {
        self.tableView = tableView
        self.textView = textView
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        addSubview(tableView)
        addSubview(textView)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func layout() {
        super.layout()
        let tableViewHeight = frame.height * 0.7
        let textViewHeight = frame.height * 0.3
        tableView.frame = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: tableViewHeight)
        textView.frame = NSRect(x: 0, y: tableViewHeight, width: frame.width, height: textViewHeight)
    }

}
```

The following invokes the CustomView in ContentView:

```
struct CustomViewRepresentable: NSViewRepresentable {
    let filesView = FilesView(files: Files())
    let textBox = TextBox()

    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSView {
        let customView = CustomView(tableView: filesView, textView: textBox)
        return customView
    }

    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSView, context: Context) {
        // Update the NSView if necessary
    }

    typealias NSViewType = NSView
}
```

Here is the implementation in ContentView:

```
private var customViewRepresentable: CustomViewRepresentable

init(){
    self.customViewRepresentable = CustomViewRepresentable()
}
```

In ContentView's body:

```
var body: some View {
    
        VStack {
            customViewRepresentable
        }
}
```

**Minimal reproducible example**:

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation
import Combine

class FilesView: NSView {
    //let files: Files
    @Published var sortDescending = false
    var tableView = NSTableView()
    var nameColumn = NSTableColumn(identifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "name"))
    var statusColumn = NSTableColumn(identifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "status"))
    var dateColumn = NSTableColumn(identifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "date"))
    var groupingColumn = NSTableColumn(identifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "grouping"))
    var durationColumn = NSTableColumn(identifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "duration"))
    init(){
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        configureTableView()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    func configureTableView() {
        print("in configureTableView()")
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.identifier = NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "cell")
        tableView.addTableColumn(nameColumn)
        tableView.addTableColumn(statusColumn)
        tableView.addTableColumn(dateColumn)
        tableView.addTableColumn(groupingColumn)
        tableView.addTableColumn(durationColumn)
        tableView.headerView = nil
        tableView.backgroundColor = .black
        tableView.usesAlternatingRowBackgroundColors = true
        tableView.gridStyleMask = .solidVerticalGridLineMask
        tableView.focusRingType = .none
        tableView.selectionHighlightStyle = .none
        tableView.rowSizeStyle = .default
        tableView.reloadData()
        //addSubview(tableView) // tableView is a subview of FilesView and FilesView is a subview of CustomView, tableView will be added as a subview of CustomView when CustomView is created and tableView is passed as a parameter.
    }
}

extension FilesView: NSTableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        return 0
    }
}

extension FilesView: NSTableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
        guard let cell = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "cell"), owner: nil) as? NSTableCellView else {
            return nil
        }
        if tableColumn == tableView.tableColumns[0] {
            cell.textField?.stringValue = ""
        } else if tableColumn == tableView.tableColumns[1] {
            cell.textField?.stringValue = ""
        }
        else if tableColumn == tableView.tableColumns[2] {
            cell.textField?.stringValue = ""
        }
        else if tableColumn == tableView.tableColumns[3] {
            cell.textField?.stringValue = ""
        }
        else if tableColumn == tableView.tableColumns[4]{
            cell.textField?.stringValue = ""
        }
        return cell
    }
}

class TextBox: NSView {
    @State private var selectedOption = 0 // 0 = strikeout, 1 = hide, 2 = underline
    @State private var text = ""
    @State private var isTextBoxHidden = false
    
    var textEditor: some View {
        TextEditor(text: $text)
            .frame(minHeight: 200)
            .padding()
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                    .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 2)
            )
    }

    var exportButton: some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            Button(action: {
                // code to export
            }) {
                Text("Export")
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
    
    override func layout() {
        super.layout()
        // layout the views
    }
}

    class CustomView: NSView {
        private let tableView: FilesView
        private let textView: TextBox
    
        init(tableView: FilesView, textView: TextBox) {
            self.tableView = tableView
            self.textView = textView
            super.init(frame: .zero)
            addSubview(tableView)
            addSubview(textView)
        }
    
        required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }
    
        override func layout() {
            super.layout()
            let tableViewHeight = frame.height * 0.7
            let textViewHeight = frame.height * 0.3
            tableView.frame = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: tableViewHeight)
            textView.frame = NSRect(x: 0, y: tableViewHeight, width: frame.width, height: textViewHeight)
        }
    
    }

    struct CustomViewRepresentable: NSViewRepresentable {
        let filesView = FilesView()
        let textBox = TextBox()
    
        func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSView {
            let customView = CustomView(tableView: filesView, textView: textBox)
            return customView
        }
    
        func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSView, context: Context) {
            // Update the NSView if necessary
        }
    
        typealias NSViewType = NSView
    }

    //let customViewRepresentable = CustomViewRepresentable()
    
//    init(){
//        self.customViewRepresentable = CustomViewRepresentable()
//    }

struct ContentView: View {
    
    private var customViewRepresentable: CustomViewRepresentable
    
    init(){
        self.customViewRepresentable = CustomViewRepresentable()
    }
    
    // Conform to the ObservableObject protocol
    var didChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
    
    var body: some View {
        
            VStack {
                customViewRepresentable
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Property wrappers like `@State` and `@ObservedObject` are for use inside a SwiftUI `View` -- not an `NSView`. Also, you shouldn't be creating `NSView`s in the `init` of a SwiftUI `View`.

Comment: To make it easier to answer your question, can you please create a [mcve]. The code you have supplied doesn't compile.

Comment: @jnpdx I attempted to provide updates per your advice, which is appreciated (but am unsure whether I made a fundamental improvement, as I am getting the same visual result). I added a minimal reproducible example and a potentially helpful note in the body of my post.

Comment: @AshleyMills I added a minimal reproducible example and a note in the body of my post that might be helpful.